# Trouble understanding change in number when popped from FPU to CPU Stack

Tags: stack-variables

So im working on an crackme and came across a couple of FPU loads and pops that confused me.

Address main 0040169E pops 80 bit value of 00000000_FED63690h from the FPU stack (ST0=4275451536.0000000000) to the CPU stack

but when put on the CPU stack its value is changed to

```
CPU Stack
Locked    Value      ASCII Comments
0028FB38  |D2000000     Ò
0028FB3C  |41EFDAC6  ÆÚïA
```

Why?

Here is the code with some comments:

```
main    00401696    PUSH EAX                                EAX=FED63690
main    00401697    FILD QWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.268]           Loads the FED63690 as a 64 bit value so -> 00000000_FED63690
main    0040169A    LEA ESP,[LOCAL.266]                     ESP=0028FB20 (loads address of string on stack), ST0=4275451536.0000000000 (which euals above number)
main    0040169E    FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.260]           POPS 80 bit value of ST0 onto program stack as 64 bit   

        LOCAL.260 is address 0028FB38

        Stack now looks like:

        CPU Stack
        Locked    Value      ASCII Comments
        0028FB38  |D2000000     Ò
        0028FB3C  |41EFDAC6  ÆÚïA


main    004016A4    FLD QWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.260]            Loads value onto FPU Stack so -> ST0=4275451536.0000000000 (Same as before)
main    004016AA    FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.264]           <%i> = -771751936.       POPS 80 bit value of ST0 onto program stack as 64 bit

        LOCAL.260 is address 0028FB28

        Stack now looks like:

        CPU Stack
        Locked    Value      ASCII Comments
        0028FB28  |D2000000     Ò
        0028FB2C  |41EFDAC6  ÆÚïA


main    004016AE    MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.265],00401469   Format => "%i"
main    004016B6    LEA EAX,[LOCAL.194]             
main    004016BC    MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.266],EAX        s => OFFSET LOCAL.194
main    004016BF    CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.sprintf>          

        Result is:

        s="-771751936"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**4275451536** is greater than `2^31` **(2147483648)** but less than `2 ^32` **(4294967296)**
so it is represented as `2^31  +  ( 2 ^31 *  ((4275451536 - 2 ^31 ) / 2^31)`
ie `2^31 * 1.990912266075611114501953125`

exponent is always written with bias (1023 for 64 bit precision) added to it  so **1054 = 0x41e**

fractional part can be written as `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/64  ..... 1/2 ^n`

```
0.984375     < 0.990912266075611114501953125 < 0.9921875

(1/2+...+1/64) <   -------                     < (1/2+....+ 1/128)
 111111
```

mantissa is approximated upto 52 bits explicitly and 1 or 0 is added implicitly

a c src that shows the conversion of your specific decimal is shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BIAS 1023
int main(void) {
    char binform[100] = {0};
    unsigned long a = 4275451536;
    _ultoa_s(a%2,&binform[0],4,10);
    a = a/2;
    int i = 1;
    while (a>2) {
        a = a/2;
        _ultoa_s(a%2,&binform[i++],4,10);
    }
    char paddedstr[100] = {0};
    sprintf_s(paddedstr,100,"%s0000000000000000000000",_strrev(binform));
    printf("%x-%I64x\n",i+BIAS,_strtoui64(&paddedstr[1],0,2));
}
```

on execution the results are

```
>F2H.exe
41e-fdac6d2000000
```

Comment: In short: The original number is not [normalized](http://www.teach-ict.com/as_as_computing/ocr/H447/F453/3_3_4/floating_point/miniweb/pg10.htm). Loading it into the FPU normalizes it, so storing it back changes the bits, but not the value.